# Adding external link to Acumatica generic inquiry.

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way in 2017 R2 to add an external link to a generic inquiry or is there a way in 2018 R2? If so, could you please enlighten.

Comment: Can you provide an example of or expand on what an external link represents. Is this a link on a GI that opens a link to a page outside of Acumatica?

Comment: Yes, I want to click on a link that is in a GI that will go to another page with information on it. The end goal is to be able to put this in the Acumatica mobile app and have the same functionality.

Comment: This feature will become available in Acumatica 2021 R2. https://community.acumatica.com/ideas/ACU-I-1539